# Heroku - migrating to Cedar 14 & updating ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku

I'm trying to migrate my heroku app to Cedar 14 (following this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration)

My problem is that heroku thinks I'm using ruby v 2.1.1 (where my machine is on ruby 2.2.2. This is confirmed by ruby -v and which ruby (both return 2.2.2).

However, when I try:

```
heroku run ruby -v
```

The return is:

```
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.4550
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
```

I can't figure out how to get heroku to recognise that ruby 2.2.2 is what should be used. It's in my gem file, I set it as the default and its in my bash profile at the top of the list.

As a result, I can't push the migration on heroku because it's not supported by older versions of ruby. I get this error:

```
Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
```

Does anyone know how to get heroku to recognise ruby v 2.2.2?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku: Error pushing Rails app to Heroku, Heroku can't find Rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760586/heroku-error-pushing-rails-app-to-heroku-heroku-cant-find-rails-app)

Answer (score 1):

You have the add the desired Ruby version to your `Gemfile` like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.4'
# ...
```

There is an article about [Specifying a Ruby Version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) in their devcenter.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated my ruby version in my gem file, and updated my path and set the default. I had installed all my gems, but I didn't update my gems. Gem update solved this for me.